# Optimising a function which finds the maximum minimum integer of a set of overlapping segments

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I recently attempted a programming challenge. While my code passed all the visible tests, it failed some of the hidden tests due to not executing quickly enough. I'm not trying to cheat; I've already submitted my code. But I thought it would be good for my growth as a programmer to piece together what I might have done better.

The problem is a bit awkward to express clearly, but I'll have a go:

- You have to write **a function**, which takes as arguments:

  1. An integer, giving the **segment length**, and
  2. A list/array/etc of integers, which is the **big list** which we're going to be chopping up to get our segments.
- We're going to chop up our big list into a set of **overlapping segments**. So if our big list was [1, 2, 3, 4] and our segment length was 2, then that would give segments [1, 2], [2, 3] and [3, 4]. If, on the other hand, our segment length was 3, then our segments would be [1, 2, 3] and [2, 3, 4].
- Now we're going to go through each of the segments that we made in the previous step, and take the **minimum** value in each one.
- Your function must **return** the **maximum** of the minima obtained in the previous step.

The original problem is designed such that you can tackle it in **any major programming language**, but I chose to write my attempt in **Python**, since that's my strongest language. This is my current code:

```py
def calculate_max_of_mins(seg_length, big_list):
    starting_index = 0
    segment = big_list[starting_index:(starting_index+seg_length)]
    result = min(segment)
    starting_index = starting_index+1
    while starting_index < len(big_list)-seg_length:
        segment = big_list[starting_index:(starting_index+seg_length)]
        if min(segment) > result:
            result = min(segment)
        starting_index = starting_index+1
    return result
```

As I stated above, my function returns the correct value, but **it's too slow** to pass all of the challenge's tests. **How could I make it faster?**

Comment: Think of a sliding window of length k,  as it slides it loses one element and gets one new one.  Unless you are removing your minimum element, your minimum doesn't change unless the new element is even smaller.

Comment: @ChristianSloper Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you may have misread the question. The function has to find the **maximum** of the minima, and not the overall minimum, which of course would be a lot more straightforward.

Comment: @ChristianSloper Hold that thought! I think I see what you're driving at now...

Comment: Each step you collect one minimum, after that it is a small task to find the maximum of those.

Comment: I think I'm with you now. Basically, `min(segment)` is O(n^2). We're trying to convert that into a more manageable process. Is that correct?

Comment: exactly.  You have to see if you can use part of the information from the previous segment

Comment: @ChristianSloper Okay, I've put together a revised solution. Would you mind if I answered my own question, using your hint?

Comment: no problem, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

A significant issue - there may be others - with the function in the question is that it calls `min(segment)` for **every** segment. Now calling `min(segment)` is expensive in terms of performace; it's O(`seg_length`) in "Big O" notation. You probably won't notice a difference in performance when `seg_length` is less than, say, 10, but once you have a `seg_length` in the thousands and a `len(big_list)` in the millions, the function will take several minutes to execute.

To resolve this issue, let's imagine we're walking through the n segments in `big_list`, from i=0 to i=n-1. Now notice that, apart from the case of i=0, **the minimum of segment i will only be different from the minimum of segment i-1 in one of the following circumstances**:

1. The minimum of segment i-1 was its first element, and thus the old minimum is not present in segment i. This is the only case - other than when i=0 - in which you will have to call `min(segment)`.
2. The last element of segment i is less than the minimum of segment i-1. In this case, the last element of segment i will be the new minimum.

By radically reducing the number of times we call `min(segment)` - as in the following code - we can improve the above function's performance considerably.

```py
def calculate_max_of_mins(seg_length, big_list):
    starting_index = 0
    segment = big_list[starting_index:(starting_index+seg_length)]
    seg_minimum = min(segment)
    index_of_minimum = segment.index(seg_minimum)
    result = seg_minimum
    starting_index = starting_index+1
    while starting_index <= len(big_list)-seg_length:
        segment = big_list[starting_index:(starting_index+seg_length)]
        if index_of_minimum < starting_index:
            seg_minimum = min(segment)
            index_of_minimum = segment.index(seg_minimum)+starting_index
        elif big_list[starting_index+seg_length-1] < seg_minimum:
            seg_minimum = big_list[starting_index+seg_length-1]
            index_of_minimum = starting_index+seg_length-1
        if seg_minimum > result:
            result = seg_minimum
        starting_index = starting_index+1
    return result
```

If anyone can think of any ways in which the **performance** of the above code could be improved even further, please do leave a comment or another answer.